# crystal reports formula's on group

Tags: crystal-reports

crystal report grouped by company and invoiced

```
company name    invoiceNo which has max(dayslate)? (maxdaysLate)
------------- records -------------------------------
```

there is a chance of one invoice is assigned to multiple companies,

for example

```
company1        inv1  30 days late (max(dayslate) col below)
    invoiceNo   duedate         dayslate (cal field today - duedate)
    inv1        2016-01-01          30
    inv2        2016-01-01          30
Company2         inv3  26 days late(inv1 below has max but already in comp1, so 2nd max)
    invoiceNo   duedate         dayslate
    inv1        2016-01-01          30
    inv3        2016-01-04          26
```

need help how to write a formula for max days late record field in a group (ex: inv1)
how to calculate max days as already one is used find second so on...

**edit**

days late is column which is calculated column (today - due date)
on group want to display which has max days late of that group and its related invoice number

there is chance of one invoice has been assigned to multiple companies, in case any that invoice has max days in 2 groups it should be calculated to only one company group and on other group it should consider the second highest

Comment: What is max days what are you looking to get from the data

Comment: can you be more descriptive? @JAVAC

Comment: @siva dayslate is calculate formula field in reports today - due date that top group have to show which as max days late for each company